# Auto positioning of tooltip using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, tooltip, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-bootstrap

I want to position my tooltip automatically, like if I am at the top of the browser scrollbar, and there is a link with the tooltip in the first line then the tooltip must be displayed at the bottommid.

Is there any way to do so using angularjs only?

I am using angular-ui-bootstrap

```
<a href="#" tooltip-template="'tool.html'" tooltip-class="customclass">My template</a>
<style>
    .tooltip.customclass .tooltip-inner {
        color: #414141;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
    }
    .tooltip.customclass .tooltip-arrow {
        display: none;}
</style>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tool.html">
    <span>Special Tooltip with <strong>markup</strong></span>
</script>`
```

Comment: you may try tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-append-to-body="true"

Comment: Tried.It is not working , if my link is at the top,then tooltip is not visible .

Answer (score 0):

We are tracking this via https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/375 and do not have a coded solution at the moment.  However, please feel free to subscribe to that issue for updates and also see [this link](https://gist.github.com/pads/3bbc1c9d45fe84b10977) from the above issue for a workaround.

Things may get a little more tricky with Bootstrap 4 as they've added a dependency on the Tether library.  We have some more research to do to figure out how this affects our library size if we support it.